# How can I add 1 second in Joda date/time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a `LocalDateTime` object `myDateTime` that I can see in the debugger that has:
`2015-12-12T23:59:59.000`
I do: `myDateTime.plusSeconds(1)` but the timestamp remains the same.
What am I messing up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most types in Joda Time (at least the ones you should use) are immutable. You can't change their value - but you can call methods which return a *new* value. You're calling the right method in this case, but you need to remember the result, e.g.

```
myDateTime = myDateTime.plusSeconds(1);
```

Comment: Hence why is named `plusSeconds` instead of `addSeconds`.

Answer (score 1):

plusSeconds() returns a copy of your current date time with the added seconds. So instead of doing myDateTime.plusSeconds(1) and using myDateTime, you would do the following:
LocalDateTime newDateTime = myDateTime.plusSeconds(1)